# '''hours were ''or ''hours was '' ''Singular'' or '' plural''

Tags: usage, passive-voice, subject-verb-agreement

Which sentence is more correct ?

> 1. Hours **were** shown by pendulum clocks.
> 2. Hours **was** shown by pendulum clocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentence 1 is correct as "hours" is plural, and the verb form should be "were". Sentence 2 is incorrect as "was" is the singular form.